# htaccess multisite config crashed after sites move to other host

Tags: multi-sites, .htaccess

I am on my long way to move my D6 site to other hosting company. It was hard but finally seems it's almost done but I am stacked on multisites configuration.
Situation is like this:

**Drupal folder (from ftp/apache access point of view)**

- /webs/drupal/site  (main )
- /webs/drupal/site/sites (multisites)

**domains:**

- www.a.com
- www.b.a.com

point to:

- /webs/drupal/

**/webs/drupal/.htaccess file**

```
#redirect to */site
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?b.a.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ site [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?a.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ site [L]
```

**/webs/drupal/site/.htaccess**

- it's standard D6 .htaccess with "always add 'www' prefix" rule on

**The problem is that I can:**

- access default site using all combinations like www.a.com, a.com, a.com/site
- access subsite like www.b.a.com/site

**but all calls like:**

- www.b.a.com
- b.a.com

**redirects to the main site www.a.com/site ...**

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's really more about writing htaccess files than about Drupal itself.

Comment: I opt, as htaccess is clean tested and working, the question here is why drupal do not call/see subsite but redirects to the main.

Comment: True enough. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5799393/2389310) and test what URL your site is actually "seeing". Put it in index.php (back up real index.php of course).

Comment: `REQUEST_URI: /site/

REDIRECT_URL: empty` in all cases, no deference for b.a.com or a.com. Have no idea what does it mean

Answer (score 1):

It was a matter of the firefox cached data. After cleaning the cache it works.